# How would basic and complex life evolve in a gas giant

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution

Obviously the chances of life arising in such inhospitable and unlikely as a gas giant are next to none. Instead let us theorize that a local orbiting moon of a Jupiter-like gas giant which contains a large amount of hydrogen in its atmosphere develops simple hydrogen oxidizing extremophile bacteria. A collision with another moon sends large chunks of rock with these bacteria hurtling into the gas giant. The bacteria float around in the atmosphere and feed on the gas giant's hydrogen rich environment. They multiply and eventually can be found all over the planet. What happens from now? Can multicellular life arise, and if it not, what is needed to allow it?

The gas giant contains large amounts of ammonia, methane and oxygen in order to help life move along.

One proposition as an energy source, much to my delight at such an interesting idea is for the organisms to use 'magnetosynthesis' by feeding on the gas giants magnetic field. This idea is courtesy of Tim B II

Comment: I've VTC because at least one answer to this question would be to outline the evolution of orders of species over millions of years in an ill-defined environment. 'Too Broad' barely covers it.

Comment: How does complex life arise from hydrogen-oxidizing extremophile bacteria introduced into a gas giant? By means of natural selection, of course, considering gas giants are rich in organic matter and has potential strong energy gradients. No different from the evolution of any biosphere. Too broad, indeed!

Comment: Idea perhaps based on [Carl Sagan's Cosmos which has a scene about gas giant life](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2013/20131023-on-hunters-floaters-and-sinkers-from-cosmos.html)

Answer (score 4):

If we take the mix of gases on Jupiter as a comparsion, your extremophile bacteria may not even survive by floating on the atmosphere alone as the amount of oxygen available for the bacteria to extract from things like water, the amount of carbon available from things like methane and the amount of nitrogen available from things like ammonia are all extremely small quantities, in a similar order of magnitude to CO<sub>2</sub> in the atmosphere on Earth.

That is to say, their chances of getting water and food is already thin on the ground, if you'll pardon the expression in this context. The thing is, you also need a range of other trace elements to keep life sustained as nutritional elements.

So; firstly you need these gases in much higher quantities, and then you need some form of energy source for the endothermic reactions required to convert these molecular compounds into carbohydrates and oxygen to feed your organisms. Even if they could metabolise hydrogen directly via mixing it with oxygen to make water, they would still need carbon for nutritional value alone as we are 'carbon based' lifeforms, not hydrogen based. Carbon, in other words, allows life to form by having a high valency, meaning that it can connect many other atoms to itself allowing for the complex molecular structures life needs.

As for the energy source, if you're talking Jupiter specifically, it's *possible* that you could have an extremophile that could absorb the EM energy of Jupiter's magnetic field in order to process the available molecules into oxygen and food, much like plants on Earth use sunlight to do the same thing through photosynthesis. This 'magnetosynthesis' could **theoretically** provide enough energy to make the chemical reactions possible, but as to whether or not this could be harnessed beyond unicellular subsistence levels (in other words, produce enough energy and oxygen in the atmosphere to allow for multicellular organisms to consume it directly) is unsure. I'd argue that at the very least, your unicellular life already has enough challenges and is likely to stay as such for hundreds of millions (if not billions) of years.

But then, so did the first life on Earth that paved the way for the Great Oxygenation Event, so perhaps this is more possible (with the right composition of gases in the atmosphere) than I give it credit for.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Magnetosynthesis seems to be a really interesting form of energy processing. Could this extrapolate into even simple multi cellular life such as small magnetosynthetic 'plants' floating around? Say with a gas giant with a much stronger magnetic field and available important gasses such as oxygen, methane and ammonia in large quantities?

Comment: @JeffereyDawson sure, it's possible, but we'd all need more detail before starting to venture into whether or not it would be probable. My guess is that if it was to happen, colonies would form in the first instance as multicellular support groups in the atmospheric currents and gravity, and multicellular life might form from there. But as I say, this is pure supposition based in part on what we think happened here on Earth and a dash of creativity.

Comment: I think I will probably base a future question on the idea of magnetosynthesis and how it could work and the possible maximum energy production from it.

Answer (score 1):

The famous astrophysicist Carl Sagan answered this question in great detail; it was one he was extremely interested in. He and E. E. Salpeter published a paper called [Particles, Environments, and Possible Ecologies in the Jovian Atmosphere](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1976ApJS...32..737S) through Cornell University where Sagan taught.

You can read that paper, which is quite dry, or you can google his concept of "hunters, floaters, and sinkers," which are the three alien types he hypothesized could reasonably evolve on a gas giant. He surmised that a planet like this could harbor not only simple, single-celled/bacterial life, but complex eukaryotes as well.

I'm not a physicist or a biologist so I won't try to give you a complex explanation, but the intense weather patterns on gas giants might catalyze heterotrophic life there, sparked into existence by frequent lightning and surviving on methane in the atmosphere. They live their entire lives as jellyfish-like critters, floating the winds of the planet, occasionally feasted upon by squid-like beings that can better control their movement.

Comment: I've already read Carl Sagan's article before and it was quite dry, but it didn't really focus on the evolutionary side of things, more on the possible catalysts for the beginning of life.

Comment: I'm not sure he'd have been able to produce much on the subject that wasn't unnecessarily speculative, given that the abiogenesis of life on Jupiter was already a highly speculative topic already. You might just have to invent your own explanations. What level of muster/scrutiny are you trying to pass with this writing project, by the way? Will it be read by biologists?